# analogue of diag operator for functions

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, definition

If $x\in{\rm I\! R}^n$, then diagonal matrix $\mathop{\rm diag}(x)$ is a linear operator $\mathop{\rm diag}(x): {\rm I\! R}^n \to {\rm I\! R}^n$.

I am curious if there is some analogy for infinite dimensional space, like if $f\in C[0,1]$ then can we define somehow $\mathop{\rm diag}(f): C[0,1] \to C[0,1]$?

Comment: what is diag(x) in R^n ?

Comment: It would be just multiplication, $(\text{diag}(f) (x))(t) = f(t)x(t)$.

Comment: Presumably $\text{diag}(x) (p) = \sum_k x_k p_k e_k$

Comment: @copper.hat: You could write that as an answer.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For $f \in C[0,1]$, we could define $\text{diag}(f):C[0,1] \to C[0,1] $  by $(\text{diag}(f) (x))(t) = f(t)x(t)$. Basically pointwise multiplication.